# How to show or hide a div on the basis of a java variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am working in an application where I am getting some variable values from user end and on the basis of that values I will open and show  a div. I am taking the values in scriplet and want to show or hide the div on the basis of that value. Here I am posting and explaining my code

```
<%
User user = (User) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.USER);              
int userIdInt = (int) user.getUserId();
List<Profile> existingProfile = ProfileLocalServiceUtil.getByUserId(userIdInt);
String address1 = "";
String address2 = "";
int countryCode = 0;
int stateCode = 0;
String city = "";
String zipCode = "";
String skypeId = "";
String twitter = "";
String primaryPhone = "";
String secondaryPhone = "";

for(int i=0;i<existingProfile.size();i++) {

    address1 = existingProfile.get(i).getAddress1();
    address2 = existingProfile.get(i).getAddress2();
    countryCode = existingProfile.get(i).getCountryId();    
    stateCode = existingProfile.get(i).getState();
    city = existingProfile.get(i).getCity();
    zipCode = existingProfile.get(i).getZipCode();
    skypeId = existingProfile.get(i).getSkypeId();
    twitter = existingProfile.get(i).getTwitter();
    primaryPhone = existingProfile.get(i).getPrimaryPhone();
    secondaryPhone = existingProfile.get(i).getSecondaryPhone();
}   

String getInsertedStateSql = "SELECT stateID, name FROM state where countryID="+countryCode;
Statement st6 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs6 = st6.executeQuery(getInsertedStateSql);

String getSelectedStateSql = "SELECT stateID, name FROM state where countryID="+countryIdOnFailedValidationInt;
Statement st7 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs7 = st7.executeQuery(getSelectedStateSql);

//System.out.println("User State Code: "+stateCode);
  %>




<div id="personalInformationDiv">
```

#### Personal Information

```
<div id="primaryLabel">
<table id="personalInformation">
        <tr>                
                <th>Address 1<span style='color: #FF0000; display: inline;'>*</span></th>   
            <td><label for="address1"><%=address1 %></label></td>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="open_new();"><img style="border:0;" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/edit.png" title="Click to edit"></a> </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>                
            <th>Address 2<span style='color: #FF0000; display: inline;'>*</span></th>   
            <td><label for="address2"><%=address2 %></label></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <th>City<span style='color: #FF0000; display: inline;'>*</span></th>
            <td><label for="city"><%=city %></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Primary Phone<span style='color: #FF0000; display: inline;'>*</span></th>
            <td><label for="primary phone" ><%=primaryPhone %></label></td>
        </tr>       
</table>
</div>
<div style="display:none;">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk">
</div>

 <div id="contentToShow">
    <table id="personalInformationShowHide">
    <tr>        
            <th>Address 1<span style='color: #FF0000; display: inline;'>*</span></th>           
        <td>
            <aui:input inlineField="true" label="" name="address1" size="45" value="<%=address1 %>"/>               
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Address 2</th>
        <td><aui:input inlineField="true" label="" name="address2" size="45" value="<%=address2 %>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Country<span style='color: #FF0000; display: inline;'>*</span></th>
        <td>
        <select id="country" name="country">
            <option value="None">- Select Country -</option>
            <%
                while (rs5.next()) {
                    int CODE = rs5.getInt("CODE");
                    String COUNTRY = rs5.getString("COUNTRY");                              
                    if( countryCode !=0 ){
                        if(validationFailed!=null){
                            if(validationFailed.equals("true")){
                                if( countryIdOnFailedValidationInt == CODE ){
                                    %>
                                    <option value="<%=countryIdOnFailedValidationInt%>" selected><%=COUNTRY%></option>
                                    <% }else{ %>
                                    <option value="<%=CODE%>"><%=COUNTRY%></option>
                                    <%
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            if( countryCode == CODE ){
                                %>
                                <option value="<%=countryCode%>" selected><%=COUNTRY%></option>
                                <% }else{ %>
                                <option value="<%=CODE%>"><%=COUNTRY%></option>
                                <%
                                }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(validationFailed!=null){
                            if(validationFailed.equals("true")){
                                if( countryIdOnFailedValidationInt == CODE ){
                                    %>
                                    <option value="<%=countryIdOnFailedValidationInt%>" selected><%=COUNTRY%></option>
                                    <% }else{ %>
                                    <option value="<%=CODE%>"><%=COUNTRY%></option>
                                    <%
                                }
                            }
                        } else { %>
                            <option value="<%=CODE%>"><%=COUNTRY%></option>
                    <%  }
                    }
                }   
            %>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <th>State</th>
        <td>
            <div id="loadDistrict">  
                 <select name="stateList" id="stateListEnglish">
                <%if(stateCode!=0){
                    if(validationFailed!=null){
                        if(validationFailed.equals("true")){
                            while (rs7.next()) {
                                int CodeState = rs7.getInt("stateID");
                                String stateName = rs7.getString("name");
                                if(stateIdOnFailedValidationInt == CodeState){
                                    %>      
                                            <option value="<%=stateIdOnFailedValidationInt%>" selected><%=stateName%></option>
                                    <%      } else {%>
                                            <option value="<%=CodeState%>"><%=stateName%></option>  
                                    <%      }
                            }   
                        }   
                    } else {
                        while (rs6.next()) {
                            int CodeState = rs6.getInt("stateID");
                            String stateName = rs6.getString("name");
                            if( CodeState == stateCode ){
                    %>          <option value="<%=stateCode%>" selected><%=stateName%></option> 
                    <%      }else{%>
                                <option value="<%=CodeState%>"><%=stateName%></option>
                    <%      }
                        }
                    }
                } else if(stateCode==0){
                %>
                <option value="None">--Select State--</option>
                <%  
                    while (rs7.next()) {
                        int CodeState = rs7.getInt("stateID");
                        String stateName = rs7.getString("name");
                        if(validationFailed.equals("true")){
                            if(stateIdOnFailedValidationInt == CodeState){
                    %>      
                            <option value="<%=stateIdOnFailedValidationInt%>" selected><%=stateName%></option>
                    <%      } else {%>
                            <option value="<%=CodeState%>"><%=stateName%></option>  
                    <%      }

                        }
                    }

                }               
                %>

                </select>
            </div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>City<span style='color: #FF0000; display: inline;'>*</span></th>
        <td><aui:input inlineField="true" label="" name="city" size="45" value="<%=city %>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Zip</th>
        <td><aui:input inlineField="true" label="" name="zip" size="45" value="<%=zipCode %>"/><span id="errmsg1"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Skype ID</th>
        <td><aui:input inlineField="true" label="" name="skypeId" size="45" value="<%=skypeId %>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Twitter</th>
        <td><aui:input inlineField="true" label="" name="twitter" size="45" value="<%=twitter %>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Primary Phone<span style='color: #FF0000; display: inline;'>*</span></th>
        <td><aui:input inlineField="true" label="" name="primaryPhone" size="45" value="<%=primaryPhone %>"/><span id="errmsg2"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Secondary Phone</th>
        <td><aui:input inlineField="true" label="" name="secondaryPhone" size="45" value="<%=secondaryPhone %>"/><span id="errmsg3"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>        
<br>    
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <aui:button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save and Continue" style="width: 160px"></aui:button>
        </td>   
        <td>
            <aui:button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Close" style="width: 160px" onclick="hideForm();"></aui:button>
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
<aui:input type="hidden" name="redirectURL" value="<%= renderResponse.createRenderURL().toString() %>"/>
```

Now what my need is that I want to show the content of contentToShow div when  the  values of address1, address2, city, primary phone are null. How would I achieve that? Somebody please help.

Comment: I see that you tagged jquery but I don't see any javascript code in your post, so basically you just answered your own question I guess, you need to use javascript to check the value of your elements, if the value is empty (basically null) then hide the div

Comment: start by giving your labels ids

Comment: No but how to get the values of java variable into javascript and check ??that what i am asking

Comment: that's what i'm going to tell you, i'm just taking it step by step, where are your java variables being written to, to the labels right?

Comment: yes sir it is in the label

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80189/discussion-between-lucifer-and-jeremy-c).

Comment: alright, so start by giving the labels ids like id='addresslabel' etc...